# Searching on complete node title in Search API fails to find that node

Tags: search

I have a site with Search API, Search Pages, and Fuzzy Search modules installed. There's no Solr or anything installed. The core search module is turned off. I have a node whose type is indexed, with title as a searchable field, whose title is "quick brown fox".

- When I search for the term `quick brown fox` nothing comes up.
- When I search for the term `quick brown` nothing comes up.
- When I search for the term `quick fox` my node comes up.
- When I search for the term `brown fox` my node comes up.
- When I search for the term `quick fox` my node comes up.
- When I search for the term `quick bro` nothing comes up.
- When I search for the term `fox brown` my node comes up.
- When I search for the term `fox quick` my node comes up.

What is going on? Why is it getting confused by anything that contains the first word and second word of the node title in that order, but seems to be finding everything else just fine?

Comment: Out of interest is it just that one node you see the behaviour for or does it affect other phrases/titles as well?

Comment: Searching the full and complete title of any node appears to not bring up that node.

Comment: Correction: Searching the full and complete title of some other nodes appears to not bring up those nodes. It's not all of them though.

Comment: Also I do not have workbench installed on this site, I just realized. So it's not the Workbench Moderation bug I thought it might be.